# Unabe to install windows on a ubuntu only machine

Tags: installation, 12.10, boot, dual-boot, windows

I am new here and this is my first post. I have an HP laptop (Pavilion dv6000)

While I was trying to dual boot Ubuntu, I was unable to install it correctly and the setup broke in the middle leaving me unable to boot.

Next I tried to install other Linux OS's but with out any luck. Finally I was able to install Ubuntu 12.10 by following the guides on the internet, but it is extreme slow and not all hardware works.

I was able to install it in a 80GiB ext4 partition where Ubuntu is installed and no other windows partitions and, now if I use the windows 7/8 LiveCD or USB then, through the bios, set it to boot using USB or CD. It still doesn't boot giving a error:

```
 an operating system wasn't found
```

This maybe because it doesn't have a Windows 8 master boot record.

Please can anybody tell me how to restore windows 8mbr and boot into the Windows installation disc, and get rid of Ubuntu? I already have it on my desktop computer, so it's not needed on my laptop.

Please help as I have to complete some important work.

Answer (score 0):

[This tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) should fix most common problems - though if Ubuntu install failed, I would try to install it over the same partition it is on, again.